# Questions should not be locked when off-topic comments are moved to chat for the first time

Tags: discussion, status-completed, locked

I my opinion, it's to early to lock a question when moving off-topic comments to the chat **for the first time**.

It's understandable when it repeats two or three times... and it certainly did in the past (that I'm pretty sure did not end with locking) but the first time should definitely leave the question open.

---

This post is based on [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221057/general-purpose-replacement-for-enum-with-flagsattribute) question that has suffered such a premature locking.

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.

Their amount wasn't that high anyway and not that different from other popular questions.

---

I'd be great if a ♦ could undo this.

Comment: I now see the _Post Unlocked by Community♦_ - has the lock automatically expired or how does this work? I'm confused and not sure what to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific question you refer to was automatically unlocked 20 minutes after you posted this question. The lock was explicitly set to automatically time out after an hour.

Discussing the specifics of this action seems to have little merit, because opinions around temporarily locking a question are almost guaranteed to be different.

Comment: That's fine. I guess ordinary users cannot see the expiration date so I wasn't sure what is actually going on there... nevertheless, I still find the locking was premature and shouldn't have happened. An information about a cool-down timeout would have also been useful.

Comment: @t3chb0t the lock timeout appears to only be visible to moderators, at least that's what [this meta bugreport suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131455/222299). If you want locks to show their timeout, you should open a [meta-tag:feature-request] on MSE.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the suggestion but I'll pass. Bad experience with such requests.

Answer (score 5):

The comments on the post were auto flagged for being excessive. Further, they are, at times unfriendly... approaching rude and abusive. I locked the post for an hour in order to force any further discussion in to chat. I believe the desired effect was achieved. I was not able to hang around and monitor the post directly, so preventative cooldown was the right thing.

I was not aware that the timeout on the lock was not visible... regardless, that is a separate issue, and is not as significant as the ugly tone of some of the comments. Perhaps they should be reviewed as well.

Comment: _I believe the desired effect was achieved._ This was a pure coincidence because I was't going to replay to any of them anymore and I had hoped the entire time the _move to chat_ button would finally appear so that I can do it myself... but it hadn't shown itself. Maybe some of the comments were slightly less than 100% polite but saying _ugly tone of some of the comments_ is meeting trouble halfway. In fact, I find the discussion was in good tone, not constructive but definitely decent.

Comment: @t3chb0t ... I consider this to be ugly _"t3chb0t 9:15
... jpmc26 this is the worst feedback ever. Unconstructive and pointless."_

Comment: I, on the other hand, consider this comment fine and your reaction to it as over-sensitive.

Comment: @t3chb0t If I would have seen a flag against that comment I would have removed it instantly. If I wouldn't have been a moderator and had seen it, I would have flagged it.

Comment: @SimonForsberg criticizing, deleting or flagging is easy so how about making it a little bit more challenging and constructive, so that everyone can learn, and you (both?) telling us how to express the same thing in a SE-conform way? Because until now all we know is that it is _ugly_; please show us, how to _un-ugly_ it.

Comment: @t3chb0t the "correct" way to handle being told the same critique over and over again is to either ignore it or to actually take it seriously and applying it. Calling it "the worst feedback ever" is downright rude.

Comment: @Vogel612 ignoring things never solves anything - it just escalates somewhere else later. I'd really like to hear how to say it so that it is _acceptable_.

Comment: @t3chb0t Tell them *what* is wrong with it, for starters. And ease off with the absolutes. "Worst ever" only indicates you haven't seen much, it says nothing about the feedback itself and doesn't help the provider with improving it.

Comment: @Mast thanks for not giving up on me, haha! This totally makes sense. You're my today's diplomacy hero ;-)